# Всегда ли @table и # располагаются в tempDB?

Tags: sql-server

Я был совершенно уверен, что временные таблицы (#) всегда находятся в tempDB: на это указывают все статьи/профильные ресурсы по sql, что я видел.

Я полагал, что @table изначально пытаются расположиться в оперативной памяти, а если в них записывается больше данных, чем может вместить память - оно скидывается в tempDB (на чём основана эта моя уверенность - сказать сложно)

Сегодня в ms doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) обнаружил следующее:

> Табличная переменная не является структурой, доступной только для памяти. Поскольку табличная переменная может содержать больше данных, чем может поместиться в памяти, она должна иметь место на диске для хранения данных. Табличные переменные создаются в tempdb базе данных аналогично временным таблицам. Если память доступна, то в памяти (кэше данных) создаются и обрабатываются как табличные переменные, так и временные таблицы.

И в этот момент я окончательно запутался. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как всё-таки это работает?

Comment: Ну, наверно придётся верить написанному: держится в памяти, пока хватает места, после чего задействуется диск. / Многие (хорошие) статьи были написаны в те времена, когда памяти на компах было намного меньше, поэтому временные таблицы практически сразу же вытеснялись на диск, полагаю, отсюда ноги растут.

Comment: табличная переменная темповой базе лежит, проверял. Можете создать переменную и поискать таблицу в tempDb

Comment: Что касается хранения данных и буферизации чтения/записи, разницы между #- и @-таблицами нет (исключение составляют memory optimized @-таблицы). Но есть и отличающиеся аспекты. Рекомендую к прочтению [вот этот](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/16385/99746) (объёмный, но стоящий того) самоответ Мартина Смита на dba.SE.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующий T-SQL.

Ключевым моментом является использование `SET STATISTICS IO ON;`. Оно покажет имя временной таблицы.

Что мы можем извлечь из этого, так это табличную переменную, которая всегда использует базу данных TEMPDB, независимо от того, сколько записей в нее было вставлено.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, City VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (City) VALUES
('New York'),
('Miami');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SET STATISTICS IO ON;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `physical reads 0` насколько я понимаю, говорит о том, что с диска ничего не читалось. Значит вставленные данные хранились в оперативной памяти.